# How to achieve routing through three different IP subnets on a Cisco router?

Tags: cisco, routing, router

I want to use a Cisco 2600 to route through four different IP subnet addresses of my servers through DHCP interconnected together with four switches on a router. How do i achieve it?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.    Can you post a diagram of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

To have the router forward dhcp packets you'll need to configure dhcp-relay on each of the router's (sub-?)interfaces that aren't local to the DHCP server.

```
interface <number>
ip helper-address <dhcp-server address>
```